# GCC changes less than to less than or equal to

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, gdb

I have the following simple program that I'm using to refresh my memory of GDB (which I haven't touched for many years).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    printf("Hello World\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I compile this with `gcc -g for-test.c -o for-test`. Based on the man page, I don't expect any optimisations to be used, since I haven't specified any.

When I load this into GDB and run `disassemble main`, the `i < 10` comparison generates the following:

```
cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x9
jle    0x4004fe <main+10>
```

This seems to have effectively changed a comparison of `i < 10` to `i <= 9`. Given that these are integer comparisons, there shouldn't be a difference, but I was wondering if there is any reason why GCC outputs this assembly, instead of comparing against 10 and jumping if less than (JL)?

Edit: This is on a machine with a 64-bit processor, running Ubuntu with GCC 4.6.3 and GDB  7.4-2012.04.

Comment: Both ways are 100% identical (same behaviour, same code size, same speed on every CPU). I don't know about GCC's internals so I can't guess why it did this. More interesting is that I don't think you've enabled optimisation (otherwise it'd be using a register instead of a local variable for `i`).

Comment: Perhaps that's how it normalizes comparisons..

Comment: If there were any chance of the two not being the same, it would not do it without optimisation. e.g. `if (a + 1 > 1)` will be simplified to `if (a > 0)` with optimisation, but it's potentially unsafe, so won't be done otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There shouldn't be a difference in execution speed. I think gcc generally emits jle for such comparisions and does it for consistency in the generated assembly.

Comment: That does seem to be the case. Interestingly, I tried the same code in clang and the result was the opposite - it would convert a 'continue loop if less than' to 'break loop if greater than or equal to'. I'm not sure why the two compilers have chosen different routes, or if one is inherently more efficient than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers are allowed to perform optimizations as long as the observable behavior is same. This is known as the **[As-If rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)**. Since the observable behavior for both the cases is same, the compiler is allowed to generate the assembly code in either of the two. This is true even if you do not have any optimizations enabled.

Comment: +1. It could even unroll the loop (it actually does that with `-O3`). And, perhaps, even print a single string that's 10 copies of the original.

Comment: This isn't really an optimisation though, unless comparing against 9 and jumping if less than or equal to is faster (or more memory efficient, or some other measure) than comparing against 10 and jumping if less than.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't effective optimization, just another way to write the same. Compiling with -O flag generates much more complex optimizations.